# AWS System Environmental Variables how-to?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

My Grails application is currently using System.env.MY_SYS_PROP and it does not work when I set the params via Beanstalk Environment Properties which get passed to the Application.
System.getProperty("MY_SYS_PROP") works but I'd like to keep the app as is with access to the properties via System.env.MY_SYS_PROP

- How do I set the System Environmental properties on AWS Beanstalk instance via config files?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using the Elastic Beanstalk environment properties as this is more flexible since it keeps the configuration external to the WAR package.

However, if you must use environment variables, you can use the Elastic Beanstalk [option_settings](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html#customize-containers-format-options) mechanism to set environment variables when container instances are created.

For Grails you can check out the [Grails Elastic Beanstalk plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/aws-elastic-beanstalk) (I am the author) that will be supporting this feature in the upcoming 0.3 release.